# Is it possible to add value to a new property of an object in js?

Tags: javascript, object, get, prototype

In js I have created an object. I want to add a new property to the object's prototype and the property will be different from instance to instance. 
Now to add value I used **get**. But it gives me error. I have added the code below.

How can I accomplish this thing?

I have googled this. And all I have learned is by **get** they add value to an existing property. But I want to add value to the new property and that will vary instance to instance.

```js
var computer = function (name, ram) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ram = ram;
};

Object.defineProperty(computer.prototype, "graphic", {
    set: function graphic(value) {
        this.graphic = value;
    },
    get: function graphic() {
        return this.graphic;
    },
});

var vio = new computer("sony", "8gb");


vio.graphic = "gtx980";

console.log(vio.graphic);
```

The error massage:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrbgt.png)

Comment: `But it gives me error` - should we guess what the error is?

Comment: you can't set a property getter/setter to it's own name. Use local vars, which is annoying on prototype methods, or get/set `this._graphic` fron `this.graphic` instead

Comment: error: `Out of stack space`, obviously.

Comment: in firefox it's `too much recursion` - which should make the problem more obvious

Comment: You can just remove all the code that adds the property.  `vio.graphic = "gtx980";` is all you need.

Comment: @Archer I want a different value for each instance.But this will add "gtx980" to all instance.

Comment: Then add a different value to each instance.  A getter and setter do not change that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rereading your question, I'll answer the actual concern:

When you put things on the prototype, they are shared between all instances (as though you add them to the class in a classical language like Java).
When you put things on `this`, they are only accessible for the specific instance.

The following works, without setters or getters:

```
function Computer(name, ram) { // Please use Capital names for constructors
    this.name = name;
    this.ram = ram;
};

let vio = new Computer('sony', '8gb');
vio.graphic = 'gtx980';
```

The `graphic` property will only exist for the instance held in `vio`, not every computer instance out there.

If, on the other hand you were to do this:

```
function Computer(name, ram) {
  this.name = name;
  this.ram = ram;
}

Computer.prototype.graphic = 'gtx980';

// All instances of Computer will now have a .graphic with the value of 'gtx980'.
```

---

The reason you're getting the error is that you define a setter for `graphic`, in it, you're trying to assign to `graphic` which invokes the setter for `graphic` which tries to assign to `graphic` which invokes.... you get the point.

The solution is to change the name of the actual variable (to, say `_graphic`).

```js
var computer = function (name, ram) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ram = ram;
};

Object.defineProperty(computer.prototype, "graphic", {
    set: function graphic(value) {
        this._graphic = value;
    },
    get: function graphic() {
        return this._graphic;
    },
});

var vio = new computer("sony", "8gb");


vio.graphic = "gtx980";

console.log(vio.graphic);
```

Note that JS doesn't really have private variables. You won't be able to prevent someone from changing `_graphic`.

Comment: Can I know the theory behind it?
if I call `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(vio));`

I get _graphic instead of graphic as property. why is that?

Comment: Because that's the actual property. Getters and setters aren't actual properties on the object, but the underlying `_graphic` is.

Comment: @zoha131 I've made an edit to explain the actual problem, instead of your attempted solution.